# "nan" instead of matrix elemets in output in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nan, sparse-matrix

I am trying to calculate an approximate solution for this sparse matrix problem Au=f, but I am getting "nan" in the output of my matrix instead of matrix elements, although the input matrices, all contain np.float64.
I don't understand where I am going wrong.

This my code :-

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
from scipy.sparse import random

#Defining a function that takes N as an input

def our_func (N) :

  #Taking the given values of parameters h and k
  h =  1/N
  k = (29*(np.pi))/2
   
  #Defining initial input matrix with domensions N+1
  I = np.empty([N+1,N+1],  dtype=np.float64) 
  #[REF :- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-an-empty-matrix-with-numpy-in-python/]
  print("datatype of I is :-")
  print(I.dtype)

  #Generating the matrix A in coo sparse format
  A_coo = coo_matrix(I).reshape((N+1,N+1))
  print("datatype of A_coo is :-")
  print(A_coo.dtype)

  #Converting the matrix A from coo sparse format to CSR sparse format 
  A = A_coo.tocsr().reshape((N+1,N+1))
  print("datatype of A is :-")
  print(A.dtype)
 
  # Creating an empty storage array for the right side of our equation Au=f
  f = np.empty((N+1), dtype=np.float64)

  #The rows of matrix A and f are defined as :-
  A[0,0] = 1    #for i==j==0
  A[N,N] = 1    #for i==j==N
  f[N] = 1      #for i==N
  f[0] = 0      #for i==0
  for i in range (int(N)) :
    for j in range (int(N)) :
        A[i,1] = 2 - ((h**2)*(k**2)) 
        A[i,i+1] = -1
        A[i,i-1] = -1
        A[i,j] = 0      #for i!==j
  
  #Our function Returns matrix A and f, with matrix A in sparse storage format
  return A, f

# Defining a new function using the function scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve 
# to solve the sparse matrix-vector problem: Au=f

def our_solution(N):
  A,f = our_func(N)
  our_sparse_matrix = scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A,f)
  return our_sparse_matrix

# Using this defined function to compute the approximate solution for our 
# problem, for N=10, N=100, and N=1000.
approx_sol_1 = our_solution(10)
print("approx_sol_1 is :- ")
print(approx_sol_1)
```

Comment: I don't know if it matters but `nan` is a flost.

Answer (score 0):

Running your function for the smaller `N`:

```
In [4]: A,f = our_func(10)
datatype of I is :-
float64
datatype of A_coo is :-
float64
datatype of A is :-
float64
C:\Users\14256\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py:103: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_intXint(row, col, x.flat[0])
```

It is warning us that setting elements of sparse `csr` array individually is not efficient.

```
In [5]: A
Out[5]: 
<11x11 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 103 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Note that is matrix is not particularly sparse, 103 out possible 121 values are non-zero.

```
In [6]: A.A
Out[6]: 
array([[  0.        ,  -1.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,  -1.        ],
       [ -1.        , -18.75084325,  -1.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],...
```

It can be pruned, getting rid of many 0s.

```
In [10]: A.eliminate_zeros()
In [11]: A
Out[11]: 
<11x11 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 28 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [17]: def my_func (N) :
    ...: 
    ...:   #Taking the given values of parameters h and k
    ...:   h =  1/N
    ...:   k = (29*(np.pi))/2
    ...: 
    ...:   #Defining initial input matrix with domensions N+1
    ...:   A = np.zeros([N+1,N+1],  dtype=np.float64)
    ...: 
    ...:   # Creating an empty storage array for the right side of our equation Au=f
    ...:   f = np.zeros((N+1), dtype=np.float64)
    ...: 
    ...:   #The rows of matrix A and f are defined as :-
    ...:   A[0,0] = 1    #for i==j==0
    ...:   A[N,N] = 1    #for i==j==N
    ...:   f[N] = 1      #for i==N
    ...:   #f[0] = 0      #for i==0
    ...:   for i in range (int(N)) :
    ...:     for j in range (int(N)) :
    ...:         A[i,1] = 2 - ((h**2)*(k**2)) 
    ...:         A[i,i+1] = -1
    ...:         A[i,i-1] = -1
    ...:         A[i,j] = 0      #for i!==j
    ...: 
    ...:   #Our function Returns matrix A and f, with matrix A in sparse storage format
    ...:   return A, f
    ...:   

In [18]: A,f = my_func(10)

In [19]: A.shape
Out[19]: (11, 11)
```

This could be converted to sparse after:

```
In [21]: M = coo_matrix(A).tocsr()
In [22]: M
Out[22]: 
<11x11 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 30 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Unless `N` is so big you hit memory errors, I think this approach would be faster.

This does not address your `nan` values issue.  I don't know enough about your problem to know whether `A` has reasonable values or not.

### edit

I wonder if that

```
A[i,j] = 0      #for i!==j
```

is too broad.  If I omit it in `my_func`, reasoning that it's already 0, there's a different `A[8,9]` value (-1).

```
In [51]: A,f = my_func(10)

In [52]: scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A,f)
C:\Users\14256\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_dsolve\linsolve.py:214: SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve requires A be CSC or CSR matrix format
  warn('spsolve requires A be CSC or CSR matrix format',
Out[52]: 
array([ 0.8987385, -0.1012615,  1.       ,  0.1012615,  0.8987385,
        1.797477 ,  1.       ,  0.1012615,  0.8987385,  1.797477 ,
        1.       ])
```

Using `A1` from `our_func`:

```
In [53]: scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A1,f)
C:\Users\14256\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_dsolve\linsolve.py:276: MatrixRankWarning: Matrix is exactly singular
  warn("Matrix is exactly singular", MatrixRankWarning)
Out[53]: array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan])
```

Correcting the sparse warning gives the same result:

```
In [54]: scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve(coo_matrix(A).tocsr(),f)
Out[54]: 
array([ 0.8987385, -0.1012615,  1.       ,  0.1012615,  0.8987385,
        1.797477 ,  1.       ,  0.1012615,  0.8987385,  1.797477 ,
        1.       ])
```

I don't know if that `A` is correct, at least it isn't singular.  Looks like `A` should have 3 diagonals, `-1, ?, -1'.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand where I am going wrong.

The `A` matrix is singular, so there is not a unique solution to the linear system you are trying to solve. You can see this because all elements of the second to last column are zero (or essentially zero) for `N=10` and `N=100`. For example:

```py
A, f = our_func(10)
A.todense()[:, -2].T
# matrix([[0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
#          0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
#          0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000,
#          0.00000000e+000, 4.69807001e-294]])
# 4.69807001e-294 is essentially 0
```

When `sparse.linalg.spsolve` encounters a (numerically) singular matrix, it emits warnings and returns an array of NaNs rather than raising an error.

```py
from scipy import sparse
A = sparse.csc_matrix((3, 3))
b = np.zeros(3)
sparse.linalg.spsolve(A, b)
# array([nan, nan, nan])
```

To fix the problem, please check the code you used to generate the matrix and ensure that it is working as intended. If you are sure that this is the linear system you are trying to solve, you need to decide what it means for the system to not have a unique solution.